# Data Too Long for column

Tags: mysql

Please help why I'm getting the error Data too long for the column, if I replace SET x = x+1 then there is no error but with x = x+2 there is data too long error.

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `LoopDemoTest`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE x INT;
    DECLARE str1 text;
    
    SET x = 1;
    SET str1 = '';
    
    DISP: LOOP
            SET x = x + 2;
        IF (x MOD 2) THEN
            SET str1 = CONCAT(str1, x, ',');
        ELSEIF (x > 10) THEN
            LEAVE DISP;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    SELECT str1;
END
```

Comment: The “Data too long for column” error occurs when you insert more data for a column that does not have the capability to store that data. For Example - If you have data type of varchar(6) that means it stores only 6 characters. Therefore, if you will give more than 6 characters, then it will give an error. `tutorialspoint`

Answer (score 0):

1. Execution NEVER fall into ELSEIF, because IF condition is always true. Use 2 separate IFs.
2. Label lost at END LOOP, must be END LOOP DISP.

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `LoopDemoTest`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE x INT;
    DECLARE str1 text;
    
    SET x = 1;
    SET str1 = '';
    
    DISP: LOOP
            SET x = x + 2;
        IF (x MOD 2) THEN
            SET str1 = CONCAT(str1, x, ',');
        END IF;
        IF (x > 10) THEN
            LEAVE DISP;
        END IF;
    END LOOP DISP;
    SELECT str1;
END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=15e86a20e1afb452f85a72276f912b95)

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes because of the if condion it's creating a problem